# Unable to access the site Using Alternate Name after Alternate Access Mappings

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-part, central-administration, configuration, alternate-access-mapping

My server name is "dev" and I need to change the name to access the site Locally and as well as on LAN.
I changed the alternate name by using AAM to "abc":

[image]

On the Local Server, it says `This page can't be displayed` if I use `http://abc/` to access the site

On the Other system on the network, it says Servers IP address could not be found:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I have tried putting the same in Intranet,Custom, Extranet Categories but the issue is same

**If I Put IP Address in place of abc, it works fine although I need to use the name to access the site instead of IP Address**

Please Help
[image]

when I add `127.0.0.1 abc`  in Host file, it repeatedly ask for authentication on the local machine & unable to access on LAN still

Comment: For further troubleshooting, please open a CMD, type the following two commands and post a screenshot here: `hostname` - `nslookup abc` - `ping abc`

Comment: @MHeld I have added the screen shot

Comment: You mistyped the commands. Please type every command and then press enter

Comment: can you please let me know the mistake I am doing in the command?

Comment: Type `hostname` and press Enter. Type `nslookup abc` and press Enter. Type `ping abc` and press Enter. Post Screenshot here.

Comment: @MHeld please check now, I have taken this from Development Server (Not Client machine)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned updating the host file on your dev machine. You need to go the sytem32\drivers\etc and update the host file with your 'abc' to machine itself.

```
127.0.0.1 abc
```

Comment: I have also tried the same, it continuously ask for authentication. please see the update

Comment: If it is continuously asking for Authentication , you may need to run the disable loopback check powershell command .

Comment: yes what Yash mentioned is correct. But it is different issue to the one you originally described. You should not update the question with the new case. You should accept an answer and ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to run the "Disable LoopBack check command" if your site is continuously asking for authentication .

Please find the reference below :-
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37664.sharepoint-2013-disable-loopback-check.aspx

Let me know in case of any concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Your DEV-Machine is not called `abc`. It's name is `dev`. So you cannot reach it with this name without workarounding configuration steps as already mentioned by others (HOSTS-File, DisableLoopbackCheck).

Why do you call this machine with `abc`? Configure everything with `dev` and you won't need any workaround.

Answer (score 0):

To access the site from another system you will need to add a DNS entry for "ABC" to point to the dev server.

Comment: already tried, it doesn't work. I've also mentioned the same in the question